# Указать размер статическо массива через конструктор

Tags: c++

Можно ли как то указать размер массива через конструктор? (нельзя использовать вектор и оператор new)

```
template<class T>
struct test{
    T arr;

    test(int size){
        arr[size];
    }
};
```

Сейчас у меня сделано так

```
template<class T, int size>
struct test{
    T arr[size];
};
```

но мне неудобно это использовать в функциях так как приходится везде указывать размер

```
bool foo(test<int, 5> & arr){
    ///.....
}
```

Comment: Проще всего использовать `std::vector`. И почему в заголовке написано *статического* массива?

Comment: не проще, мне нужно наоборот избавится от вектора

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович, нет... в С++ это невозможно... что же касается удобства — сделай `typedef test<int, 5> i5Arr;` и пользуйся наздоровье...

Comment: Ответ: нет, нельзя.

Comment: В чем смысл избавления от вектора?

Answer (score 2):

Размер массива (если не используются какие-нибудь GCC расширения для VLA - Variable Length Array) должен быть известен на этапе компиляции. Соответственно передать число, задающее этот размер в ран-тайме через параметр конструктора (или как-то ещё) не представляется возможным.

Нужен размер, известный в ран-тайме - используйте `std::vector`.

Comment: А как вы предлагаете VLA использовать для члена класса? (не троллинг, действительно интересно - как это сделать?)

Comment: @Harry возможно, это не совсем VLA, а [flexible array member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412749/3240681)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем эти мучения при RAII?

```
template<class T>
struct test{
    T * arr;

    test(int size):arr(new T[size]){}
    ~test() { delete[] arr; }
};
```

Ну и соответствующие копирующий конструктор, присвоение etc... Почему так важен именно статический массив? (Его размер обязан быть известен во время компиляции, чтоб знать размер памяти - как вы скажете, например, чему равен `sizeof(test)`?)

Comment: получился не статический массив

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович Что вы называете "статическим массивом"?

Comment: мне нельзя выделять память не могу исполщьзовать new

Comment: [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy?r=SearchResults&s=1|28.7236)? Расскажите, что и куда надо забить, и будем думать, каким молотком, а то вы пока спрашиваете, какой рукой держать микроскоп...

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович Нельзя выделять в куче? Тогда вариант в вопросе - по сути единственный. Почему нельзя, кстати?

Comment: Запретили new? юзайте malloc! Есть еще calloc

Comment: да и вообще std::allocator есть